# unable to make hebrew characters visible on the pdf,generated by vf page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, render, visualforce, hebrew

we have a vf page in our org,we are passing some  field values in hebrew language,but when the pdf is generated for that input,hebrew character coming in reverse way.for this problem,we tried to add font family,arial unicode ms in tr tag,it helped to see the hebrew characters in pdf,but the characters are coming in reverse wayi.e every letter of word is getting reveresed,we have set render as pdf for this vf page..any solution?

we are expecting to see the hebrew characters perfectly (as it is entered)on the pdf,we tried adding the Font Family-Arial Unicode MS in  tag ,but the characters/letters are getting reveresed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you experimented with `dir="rtl"` attribute available on many tags like [pageBlock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlock.htm) or [outputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm)?

Check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/143750/799 too.